# Нужно переводить числа в слова

Tags: c, float, double

Мне нужно переводить числа в слова. Код на С, у меня есть число, к примеру `142,13` (целые это рубли, а после запятой копейки).

С целыми мне ясно как делать, а вот как сделать для чисел после запятой не знаю.

Comment: Если вы не знаете как из дробного числа получить два целых, которые по отдельности представляют целую и дробную часть, то посмотрите в сторону [`modf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/). Если проблема в чём-то другом, то поясните подробнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копейки - это два, и только два знака после запятой. Переводим сумму в копейки и берем остаток от деления на рубли :)

```
int kop = int(roubles*100)%100;
```

Далее - по той же схеме, что и для целых рублей...

Comment: Точно, как-то сразу в голову не пришло, спасибо:)

Comment: @Harry, если  roubles это double, то наверное нужно   int(roubles*100)%100

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Исправил